# how can I synchronise a sequence of actions on two sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccaction

I have two sprites that I want to run a sequence of actions on. Though one sprite is created before the other I would like the latter sprites actions to synchronise with the former. How can this be achieved bearing in mind that some actions of the latter sprite might have to be skipped initially to achieve the synchronisation of the two.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no inbuilt mechanism to achieve what you want. IMO you can create both the sprites and run the sequence action on both simultaneously keeping the second sprite hidden until the time it needs to be shown on screen.

Comment: You may be better of controlling this kind of thing through your own methods and not using actions.  Actions have a very "set it and forget it" mentality.  I've found if you break that model things that can get rather tricky.